# Broadcasting a message using Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I have an app sending messages which should be broadcasted to every currently connected client. Lets say the clients count could go in thousands. How do I achieve this broadcasting logic without blocking?

Sample code that I think will block:

```
clients = []

class Broadcaster(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
   def on_message(self, message):
       for client in clients:
           self.write_message(message)
```

Every example I found on the web was like the above code. There were some examples using `@gen.coroutine` but I don't understand how this decorator could help in this scenario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WebSocketHandler.write_message` does not block on network I/O, so it will be pretty fast, although it can still add up if you have huge numbers of clients. I suggest doing some performance testing to see how long it will actually take to broadcast a message (remember the size of the message matters, too, and it will be much faster to write a byte string than a dict since the dict will be re-encoded as json every time). If it turns out to take longer than you can tolerate blocking in your application, add a `yield gen.moment` to the loop periodically:

```
@gen.coroutine
def broadcast_message(self, message):
    count = 0
    for client in self.clients:
        client.write_message(message)
        count += 1
        if count % 100 == 0:
            yield gen.moment
```

Comment: How to get all clients?

Comment: You have access to each client as it is created in `open()`. Save them in a global list or whatever data structure is appropriate for your application. See the websocket chat demo: https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid this `for` loop there if this message can go to thousands as you said. I suggest you'd use a task service, like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), to deliver the message.
Then it'd be like:

```
clients = []

class Broadcaster(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
   def on_message(self, message):
       for client in clients:
           celery_task(message)
```

and the `celery_task()` method will be a celery task method

```
@app.task
def celery_task(message):
    //logic
```

Then a task will be added to the queue and each task will send the message you desire to your clients. 
I hope that helps.

Comment: But this broadcasting logic must work real-time. Also I'd rather stick to the `Tornado` framweork alone if possible.

Comment: I think it depends on what do you have in your mind about "real-time". I mean, seconds are okay or, for example, minutes are okay too? 'Cause if minutes are okay, the task service still works. (Maybe i've not understood exactly your point there :/ )

Comment: Hmmm... Imagine a chat application - Bruce Willis has 5 minutes to talk to his fans - they log on a website and ask him questions, and they'd like to see his responses immediatelly. Maybe a few seconds would be ok, but I'd rather have it sent right when Bruce Willis presses enter :).

Comment: Or a big discount in some popular store - discount that is active for a minute or so... - then seconds would matter. This is purely theoretical question since I'm not writing anything like that, but I'm curious - how to do that :)

Comment: theoretically, you could use a socket handler using JS, something like socket.io with tornadio2